# Won't pass thru second else if condition Matlab

Tags: matlab, if-statement

```
clear;
clc;
%% INPUT DATA
input_data = [200 10.0 0.0095                                           %C1
              240  7.0 0.0070                                           %C2
              200 11.0 0.0090                                           %C3
              220  8.5 0.0090                                           %C4
              220 10.5 0.0080];                                         %C5

                        %P1    %P2      %P3    %P4       %P5
            loss_data = [0.0015 0        0      0         0             
                         0      0.0014   0      0         0
                         0      0       -0.0001 0         0
                         0      0        0      0.0009    0
                         0      0        0      0        -0.0004];   

             mwlimits = [ 50  200
                         100  500
                          50  150
                          80  300
                          50  200];        



                       pd=830;   %Power Demand
%%
lambda = input ('Enter initial lambda:')

i=1;
while i <= 6 
    fprintf('ITERATION %d \n\n', i);

p1=(lambda-input_data(1,2))/(2*(input_data(1,3)+(lambda*loss_data(1,1))));
p2=(lambda-input_data(2,2))/(2*(input_data(2,3)+(lambda*loss_data(2,2))));
p3=(lambda-input_data(3,2))/(2*(input_data(3,3)+(lambda*loss_data(3,3))));
p4=(lambda-input_data(4,2))/(2*(input_data(4,3)+(lambda*loss_data(4,4))));
p5=(lambda-input_data(5,2))/(2*(input_data(5,3)+(lambda*loss_data(5,5))));
fprintf('\tP1: %5.4f\n', p1);
fprintf('\tP2: %5.4f\n', p2);
fprintf('\tP3: %5.4f\n', p3);
fprintf('\tP4: %5.4f\n', p4);
fprintf('\tP5: %5.4f\n\n', p5);




% END OF CHECKING LIMITS %

%VERIFYING IF IT MET THE CONDITIONS%
ploss=(loss_data(1,1)*(p1))+(loss_data(2,2)*(p2))+(loss_data(3,3)*(p3))+(loss_data(4,4)*(p4))+(loss_data(5,5)*(p5));
fprintf('\tPloss: %5.4f\n', ploss);

delta_p=pd+ploss-p1-p2-p3-p4-p5;
fprintf('\tDelta P: %5.4f\n', delta_p);

if (delta_p~=0)   %General Case%

    summation=((input_data(1,3)+(loss_data(1,1)*input_data(1,2)))/(2*(input_data(1,3)+(lambda*loss_data(1,1)))^2))+((input_data(2,3)+(loss_data(2,2)*input_data(2,2)))/(2*(input_data(2,3)+(lambda*loss_data(2,2)))^2))+((input_data(3,3)+(loss_data(3,3)*input_data(3,2)))/(2*(input_data(3,3)+(lambda*loss_data(3,3)))^2))+((input_data(4,3)+(loss_data(4,4)*input_data(4,2)))/(2*(input_data(4,3)+(lambda*loss_data(4,4)))^2))+((input_data(5,3)+(loss_data(5,5)*input_data(5,2)))/(2*(input_data(5,3)+(lambda*loss_data(5,5)))^2));
    fprintf('\tSummation: %5.10f\n', summation);

 else if (delta_p==0)&& (p1>mwlimits(1,2)) %Start of P1 random
         p1=mwlimits(1,2);
        fprintf('\tP1 new: %5.4f', p1);

    delta_p=pd+ploss-p1-p2-p3-p4-p5;
    summation=((input_data(2,3)+(loss_data(2,2)*input_data(2,2)))/(2*(input_data(2,3)+(lambda*loss_data(2,2)))^2))+((input_data(3,3)+(loss_data(3,3)*input_data(3,2)))/(2*(input_data(3,3)+(lambda*loss_data(3,3)))^2))+((input_data(4,3)+(loss_data(4,4)*input_data(4,2)))/(2*(input_data(4,3)+(lambda*loss_data(4,4)))^2))+((input_data(5,3)+(loss_data(5,5)*input_data(5,2)))/(2*(input_data(5,3)+(lambda*loss_data(5,5)))^2));
    fprintf('\tSummation: %5.10f\n', summation);    


else if (delta_p==0)&& (p1<mwlimits(1,1)) 
    p1=mwlimits(1,1);
    fprintf('\tP1 new: %5.4f', p1); 

    delta_p=pd+ploss-p1-p2-p3-p4-p5;
    summation=((input_data(2,3)+(loss_data(2,2)*input_data(2,2)))/(2*(input_data(2,3)+(lambda*loss_data(2,2)))^2))+((input_data(3,3)+(loss_data(3,3)*input_data(3,2)))/(2*(input_data(3,3)+(lambda*loss_data(3,3)))^2))+((input_data(4,3)+(loss_data(4,4)*input_data(4,2)))/(2*(input_data(4,3)+(lambda*loss_data(4,4)))^2))+((input_data(5,3)+(loss_data(5,5)*input_data(5,2)))/(2*(input_data(5,3)+(lambda*loss_data(5,5)))^2));
    fprintf('\tSummation: %5.10f\n', summation);    

else if(delta_p==0)&&((p1>mwlimits(1,1))&&(p1<mwlimits(1,2)))
        p1=p1;
         fprintf('\tP1 new: %5.4f', p1);

    delta_p=pd+ploss-p1-p2-p3-p4-p5;
    summation=((input_data(1,3)+(loss_data(1,1)*input_data(1,2)))/(2*(input_data(1,3)+(lambda*loss_data(1,1)))^2))+((input_data(2,3)+(loss_data(2,2)*input_data(2,2)))/(2*(input_data(2,3)+(lambda*loss_data(2,2)))^2))+((input_data(3,3)+(loss_data(3,3)*input_data(3,2)))/(2*(input_data(3,3)+(lambda*loss_data(3,3)))^2))+((input_data(4,3)+(loss_data(4,4)*input_data(4,2)))/(2*(input_data(4,3)+(lambda*loss_data(4,4)))^2))+((input_data(5,3)+(loss_data(5,5)*input_data(5,2)))/(2*(input_data(5,3)+(lambda*loss_data(5,5)))^2));
    fprintf('\tSummation: %5.10f\n', summation); 
    end
    end
    end   %End of p1 random

if (delta_p==0)&& (p2>mwlimits(2,2)) %Start of P2 random
         p2=mwlimits(2,2);
        fprintf('\tP2 new: %5.4f', p2);

    delta_p=pd+ploss-p1-p2-p3-p4-p5;
    summation=((input_data(1,3)+(loss_data(1,1)*input_data(1,2)))/(2*(input_data(1,3)+(lambda*loss_data(1,1)))^2))+((input_data(3,3)+(loss_data(3,3)*input_data(3,2)))/(2*(input_data(3,3)+(lambda*loss_data(3,3)))^2))+((input_data(4,3)+(loss_data(4,4)*input_data(4,2)))/(2*(input_data(4,3)+(lambda*loss_data(4,4)))^2))+((input_data(5,3)+(loss_data(5,5)*input_data(5,2)))/(2*(input_data(5,3)+(lambda*loss_data(5,5)))^2));
    fprintf('\tSummation: %5.10f\n', summation);    

else if (delta_p==0)&& (p2<mwlimits(2,1)) 
    p2=mwlimits(2,1);
    fprintf('\tP2 new: %5.4f', p2); 

    delta_p=pd+ploss-p1-p2-p3-p4-p5;
    summation=((input_data(1,3)+(loss_data(1,1)*input_data(1,2)))/(2*(input_data(1,3)+(lambda*loss_data(1,1)))^2))+((input_data(3,3)+(loss_data(3,3)*input_data(3,2)))/(2*(input_data(3,3)+(lambda*loss_data(3,3)))^2))+((input_data(4,3)+(loss_data(4,4)*input_data(4,2)))/(2*(input_data(4,3)+(lambda*loss_data(4,4)))^2))+((input_data(5,3)+(loss_data(5,5)*input_data(5,2)))/(2*(input_data(5,3)+(lambda*loss_data(5,5)))^2));
    fprintf('\tSummation: %5.10f\n', summation);    

else if(delta_p==0)&&((p2>mwlimits(2,1))&&(p2<mwlimits(2,2)))
    p2=p2;
    fprintf('\tP2 new: %5.4f', p2);

    delta_p=pd+ploss-p1-p2-p3-p4-p5;
    summation=((input_data(1,3)+(loss_data(1,1)*input_data(1,2)))/(2*(input_data(1,3)+(lambda*loss_data(1,1)))^2))+((input_data(2,3)+(loss_data(2,2)*input_data(2,2)))/(2*(input_data(2,3)+(lambda*loss_data(2,2)))^2))+((input_data(3,3)+(loss_data(3,3)*input_data(3,2)))/(2*(input_data(3,3)+(lambda*loss_data(3,3)))^2))+((input_data(4,3)+(loss_data(4,4)*input_data(4,2)))/(2*(input_data(4,3)+(lambda*loss_data(4,4)))^2))+((input_data(5,3)+(loss_data(5,5)*input_data(5,2)))/(2*(input_data(5,3)+(lambda*loss_data(5,5)))^2));
    fprintf('\tSummation: %5.10f\n', summation); 
    end    
    end    
    end  %End of p2 random 


if (delta_p==0)&& (p5>mwlimits(5,2)) %Start of P5 random
         p5=mwlimits(5,2);
        fprintf('\tP5 new: %5.4f', p5);

    delta_p=pd+ploss-p1-p2-p3-p4-p5;
    summation=((input_data(1,3)+(loss_data(1,1)*input_data(1,2)))/(2*(input_data(1,3)+(lambda*loss_data(1,1)))^2))+((input_data(2,3)+(loss_data(2,2)*input_data(2,2)))/(2*(input_data(2,3)+(lambda*loss_data(2,2)))^2))+((input_data(3,3)+(loss_data(3,3)*input_data(3,2)))/(2*(input_data(3,3)+(lambda*loss_data(3,3)))^2))+((input_data(4,3)+(loss_data(4,4)*input_data(4,2)))/(2*(input_data(4,3)+(lambda*loss_data(4,4)))^2));
    fprintf('\tSummation: %5.10f\n', summation);    

else if (delta_p==0)&& (p5<mwlimits(5,1)) 
    p5=mwlimits(5,1);
    fprintf('\tP5 new: %5.4f', p5); 

    delta_p=pd+ploss-p1-p2-p3-p4-p5;
    summation=((input_data(1,3)+(loss_data(1,1)*input_data(1,2)))/(2*(input_data(1,3)+(lambda*loss_data(1,1)))^2))+((input_data(2,3)+(loss_data(2,2)*input_data(2,2)))/(2*(input_data(2,3)+(lambda*loss_data(2,2)))^2))+((input_data(3,3)+(loss_data(3,3)*input_data(3,2)))/(2*(input_data(3,3)+(lambda*loss_data(3,3)))^2))+((input_data(4,3)+(loss_data(4,4)*input_data(4,2)))/(2*(input_data(4,3)+(lambda*loss_data(4,4)))^2));
    fprintf('\tSummation: %5.10f\n', summation);    

else if(delta_p==0)&&((p5>mwlimits(5,1))&&(p2<mwlimits(5,2)))
    p5=p5;
    fprintf('\tP5 new: %5.4f', p5);

    delta_p=pd+ploss-p1-p2-p3-p4-p5;
    summation=((input_data(1,3)+(loss_data(1,1)*input_data(1,2)))/(2*(input_data(1,3)+(lambda*loss_data(1,1)))^2))+((input_data(2,3)+(loss_data(2,2)*input_data(2,2)))/(2*(input_data(2,3)+(lambda*loss_data(2,2)))^2))+((input_data(3,3)+(loss_data(3,3)*input_data(3,2)))/(2*(input_data(3,3)+(lambda*loss_data(3,3)))^2))+((input_data(4,3)+(loss_data(4,4)*input_data(4,2)))/(2*(input_data(4,3)+(lambda*loss_data(4,4)))^2))+((input_data(5,3)+(loss_data(5,5)*input_data(5,2)))/(2*(input_data(5,3)+(lambda*loss_data(5,5)))^2));
    fprintf('\tSummation: %5.10f\n', summation); 
    end    
    end    
    end  %End of p5 random     


end
 delta_lambda= delta_p/summation;
    fprintf('\tDelta Lambda: %5.4f\n', delta_lambda);

    lambda= lambda+delta_lambda;
    fprintf('The new lambda =');disp (lambda);

i=i+1;
end
```

Could anyone help me determine why it would jump the 2nd else-if statement> Or why it would skip updating value of P5? MUCH THANKS!I am really confused on why it will not pass thru the second condition. I really need this to work, but I dont understand why it would be that way. This is actually and economic dispatch problem which I tried to update/pegged the value of P5 within limits.

Comment: Sorry for the caps. I greatly aplogize. I have added the data now.

Comment: I'm new so I'm not really good in putting  codes via stackoverflow. Sorry

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the `else if` that doesn't behave the way you expect. Run your script. When it stops, check the values of `delta_p` and `p5`. Do those values make the logical statement true? If not, then execution is not going to enter that block of code.

Comment: Thanks I have learned a lot from you sir! But, I don't understand your question with respect to octave that's why I did not answer

Comment: What do you mean by that Sir beaker? Sorry I'm a newbie in coding.

Comment: @beaker was referring to this: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html (when there are more than one commentators other than you, you need to add `@` before the username of the person to send notification)

Comment: I actually solve an analytical solution based on Lagrange multipliers Sir, the problem is that, my numerical answers  via Matlab wound not coincide. I guess this is mainly due on the conditions of my code.

Comment: Oh okay Sir @SardarUsama! Thanks for helping me!

Comment: What initial lambda do you use when you execute your script?

Comment: I used lambda=9 Sir @beaker!

Comment: When I run this, `P5` is updated on each of the 6 iterations. What exactly is happening here that you don't expect, and what are the desired results?

Comment: I expected for P5 to be pegged on P5(max) Sir @beaker. But, in my code, the value is still the same for 5th and 6th iteration. Using Analytical solution thru Lagrange Multipliers resulted to P1=109.09, P2=362.42, P3=60.67, P4=198.88, P5=99.73 and optimized lambda=12.0908.

Comment: By the way sir @beaker, It's just a portion of the conditions I wanted. I tried to make P5 work first as basis.

Comment: Well, you're only executing the first block of `if/else` because `delta_p` never reaches 0. On the 6th iterations, `delta_p = -1.0936e-09`.

Comment: So it would be better sir @beaker , if I assign a stopping criterion approximately equal to zero?

Comment: I would think so. I'm not familiar with what you're doing, so perhaps more iterations are necessary to get a more accurate value, but comparing floating-point values to 0 (or any other fixed value) is almost never a good idea.

Comment: With respect to the code sir, are there any major errors? Or just the constants i set? @beaker

Comment: Sir @SardarUsama , are there other reasons for these to not meet my answers analytically? What do u think? thanks

Comment: I really can't comment on the mathematics side of it. From the programming side, there are sections that could be much more concise, for example `p1` through `p5` would be better put in an array as `p = lambda-input_data(:,2))/(2*(input_data(:,3)+(lambda*diag(loss_data)))`, and there seems to be a lot of repeated calculations in each of the `else` clauses but I haven't compared them thoroughly.